# Complex functions that worked in gcc4x do not work in gcc8x

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, complex-numbers

I am trying to get the following to build in RHEL8 with gcc 8.2.1. This previously worked with RHEL7 using gcc 4.8.5.

```
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <complex>
vector<complex<float> > x, y;

transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), conj<float>);
```

I get an error no matching function for call to the above line and points to closing ')'
The same error arises if I try other complex functions in place of `conj`, i.e. `arg`, `norm`.
Other `complex<float>` operations using transform do work, such as
`transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), bind2nd(minus<complex<float> >(), someComplexFloat));`
where `someComplexFloat` is of type `complex<float> someComplexFloat;`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[`std::conj`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/conj) has several (template) overloads since C++11, so it is ambiguous.

Way to pass overload set is to use lambda

```
std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), [](auto c){ return std::conj(c); });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2393367e512958b2).

Comment: As written, the above suggestion does not compile. Even when a closing '}' is added after the conj(c); } ); .    I get an error:
error: 'c' does not name a type
Any other suggestions?

Comment: @David: typo fixed, Demo added. if you are in C++11, you don't have generic lambda, and you should replace `auto` by `std::complex<float>`.